# Term for "sum of durations"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, measuring-units

While writing to a friend, I attempted to ask which web browser they used most. In the end, I asked which browser they used “more frequently”, but this was not the true object of my curiosity.  By using *frequently*, I effectively asked which browser they **turn on** more times within a period of time.

I also considered using the term *volume*, as in, “use with the greatest volume”, but that would have also been incorrect. I would rather use that term solely in reference to cubic measurement.

Specifically, I would have preferred to indicate the sum of durations; perhaps:

> Over a period of time, which browser is used for the greatest part of that period?

Is there such a term?

Comment: The usual metaphor theme is [`Time` Is `Money`](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf); this licenses the use of _spend_ with objects representing temporal duration. So the answer is that one should ask which browser they _spent the most time using_.

Comment: @John Lawler I'm biased toward answers that reinforce my own views.  I'd +1 if I had enough rep. :|

Comment: @Jack Stout: I think I see what you're getting at: With which browser is the user most active? Suppose a user likes to use Browser A for passively listening to music but uses Browser B to actively surf, check e-mail, etc. Suppose further that the user always loads/closes both browsers simultaneously. You want to ask a question that gives you Browser B, the one the user interacts with most, only?

Comment: @dingo_dan That is correct.  Browser B, would be the response I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'd add this as a comment, but don't have the rep, I guess).

Be sure to specify interaction.   @John-Lawler's answer sounds about right to me, but "using" is not specific enough; in @dingo_dan's example, Browser A is being *used* as much, at least in the sense that it is on *and in use* for the same amount of time.    So maybe "With which browser do you spend the most time interacting?" or "... spend the most time using interactively?".